# Can I extract the nth "chunk" from this data?

Tags: awk, sed, scripting

I have `stdout` with lots of blocks of text that look something like this:

```
% QUESTION
Who played drums for The Beatles?


% QUESTION
Who played
guitar

for The Beatles?


% QUESTION
Who played

bass for The Beatles

?
```

The idea here is that the file is divided into "chunks" where each chunk begins with the line `% QUESTION`. I'd like to write a script that will print the nth chunk of this data.

For example, issuing `nthchunk 3` should print

```
Who played

bass for The Beatles

?
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Genuinely curious why the downvote. Is there something wrong with this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `awk` implementations that support a regexp as their record separator (`RS`) such as GNU `awk`, you could do:

```
awk -v n=3 -v RS='(\n+|^)% QUESTION\n' 'NR == n+1 {print; exit}' < questions.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to write a script that will print the nth chunk of this data.

Setting `RS` and `ORS`, you can get each question this way for example:

it requires **GNU awk for multi-char RS**

```
awk -v RS='% QUESTION'  -v ORS='' '/\<drums\>/ {print $0}' file

Who played drums for The Beatles?
```

- or `bass`

```
awk -v RS='% QUESTION'  -v ORS='' '/\<bass\>/ {print $0}' file

Who played

bass for The Beatles

?
```

- or `guitar`:

```
awk -v RS='% QUESTION'  -v ORS='' '/\<guitar\>/ {print $0}' file

Who played
guitar

for The Beatles?
```

- or using a number for chunk instead

```
$ nchunk=3
awk -v nchunk="$nchunk" -v RS='% QUESTION'  -v ORS=''  'NR==nchunk+1 {print $0}' file

Who played

bass for The Beatles

?
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>GNU sed</kbd> employing the extended regex mode `-E` will be used to solve this problem. Basic idea is to accumulate the consecutive % question lines and the lines in between in the pattern space. Whilst the counter is kept in the hold space as a string of dots.

```
chunk=2
sed -E ':loop
  /%/,/%/N
  /%.*%/!{
    /%/!d;$!bloop
    s/$/\nfiller/
  }
  G;s/$/./
  /\n[.]{'"${chunk}"'}$/bend
  h;s/.*\n//;x
  s/.*(\n.*)\n.*$/\1/;D
  :end
  s/^[^\n]*\n+(\S.*\S)(\n.*){2}$/\1/
  q
' file
```

---

Alternatively, perl in slurp mode with FS set to question lines. The array @F's elements shall be the chunks.

```
perl \
  -F'/(?:^|\n+)\%\h+QUESTION\n+/' \
  -pals -0777 \
  -e '$_=$F[$n]' \
-- -n="${chunk}" ./file;
```

Output:

```
Who played
guitar

for The Beatles?
```